# Issues smoothing out data

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, smoothing

I'm trying to smooth my 2D array. I'm sure there is a better way, but I haven't found it yet. So far I'm using this bit of code to smooth it out.

You can see in the after that there are some area where a single entry went up/down in the wrong direction. It leaves a single pixel looking darker/lighter than everything around it.

What am I doing wrong in the smoothing out of my data?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapChunkSize + 2; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < mapChunkSize + 2; x++) {
                    int count = 0;
                    int dir = 0;
                    if (x - 1 >= 0 && y - 1 >= 0 && noiseMap [x - 1, y - 1] != noiseMap [x, y]) {
                        count += 1;
                        if (noiseMap [x - 1, y - 1] > noiseMap [x, y]) {
                            dir += 1;
                        } else {
                            dir -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (x - 1 >= 0 && noiseMap [x - 1, y] != noiseMap [x, y]) {
                        count += 1;
                        if (noiseMap [x - 1, y] > noiseMap [x, y]) {
                            dir += 1;
                        } else {
                            dir -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (x - 1 >= 0 && y + 1 <= mapChunkSize && noiseMap [x - 1, y + 1] != noiseMap [x, y]) {
                        count += 1;
                        if (noiseMap [x - 1, y + 1] > noiseMap [x, y]) {
                            dir += 1;
                        } else {
                            dir -= 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (y - 1 >= 0 && noiseMap [x, y - 1] != noiseMap [x, y]) {
                        count += 1;
                        if (noiseMap [x, y - 1] > noiseMap [x, y]) {
                            dir += 1;
                        } else {
                            dir -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (y + 1 <= mapChunkSize && noiseMap [x, y + 1] != noiseMap [x, y]) {
                        count += 1;
                        if (noiseMap [x, y + 1] > noiseMap [x, y]) {
                            dir += 1;
                        } else {
                            dir -= 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (x + 1 <= mapChunkSize && y - 1 >= 0 && noiseMap [x + 1, y - 1] != noiseMap [x, y]) {
                        count += 1;
                        if (noiseMap [x + 1, y - 1] > noiseMap [x, y]) {
                            dir += 1;
                        } else {
                            dir -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (x + 1 <= mapChunkSize && noiseMap [x + 1, y] != noiseMap [x, y]) {
                        count += 1;
                        if (noiseMap [x + 1, y] > noiseMap [x, y]) {
                            dir += 1;
                        } else {
                            dir -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (x + 1 <= mapChunkSize && y + 1 <= mapChunkSize && noiseMap [x + 1, y + 1] != noiseMap [x, y]) {
                        count += 1;
                        if (noiseMap [x + 1, y + 1] > noiseMap [x, y]) {
                            dir += 1;
                        } else {
                            dir -= 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (count > 4) {
                        if (dir > 0) {
                            noiseMap [x, y] += stepHeight;
                        }
                        if (dir < 0) {
                            noiseMap [x, y] -= stepHeight;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: One easy thing to try is to use a source and a destination array so that every smoothed value you produce is derived only from unsmoothed values, and never from values that have already been smoothed.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks like a nightmare to debug. That being said, I've seen image artefacts like that before, and it looks suspiciously like what mcdowella suggested : you are assigning to the 2D array while simultaneously reading from it, thus causing your checks to be inaccuarate. It's hard to decipher though.

I'm certain you can get the same behavior by simply ramping the average of a cell's neighbors. The following example should hopefully do the trick (its untested, but hopefully conveys the idea):

```
//Assumes all height values in the 2D array are normalized between 0-1
float[,] RampAverage( float[,] values, int rampSteps){
    int valuesWidth = values.GetLength(0);
    int valuesHeight = values.GetLength(1);
    float[,] tempValues = new float[valuesWidth,valuesHeight];

    for (int x = 0; x < valuesWidth; x ++){
        for(int y = 0; y < valuesHeight; y++){
            Vector2 key = new Vector2(x,y);
            float neighborAverage = GetNeighborAverage(values,key);
            tempValues[x,y] = Ramp(neighborAverage,rampSteps);
        }
    }

    return tempValues;
}

// Assumes all values are between 0-1
float Ramp(float value, int rampSteps){
    float step = 1/rampSteps;
    int d = Mathf.FloorToInt(value/step);
    return d*step;
}

float GetNeighborAverage(float[,] values, Vector2 key){
    int contributors = 0;
    float value = 0;

    int maxX = values.GetLength(0)-1;
    int maxY = valuse.GetLength(1)-1;

    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
    {
        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        {
            int xIndex = x + (int)key.x;
            int yIndex = y + (int)key.y;
            if (xIndex >= 0 && yIndex >= 0 && xIndex <= maxX-1 && yIndex <= maxY-1)
            {
                value += values[xIndex,yIndex];
                contributors ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return value/contributors;
}
```